# preg_split with two delimiters in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, split, preg-split

How to merge two delimiters in `preg_split`? For example:

```
$str = "this is a test , and more";
$array = preg_split('/( |,)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($array);
```

will produce an array as

```
Array
(
    [0] => this
    [1] =>  
    [2] => is
    [3] =>  
    [4] => a
    [5] =>  
    [6] => test
    [7] =>  
    [8] => 
    [9] => ,
    [10] => 
    [11] =>  
    [12] => and
    [13] =>  
    [14] => more
)
```

but I want to get

```
Array
(
    [0] => this
    [1] =>  
    [2] => is
    [3] =>  
    [4] => a
    [5] =>  
    [6] => test
    [7] => ,
    [8] => and
    [9] =>  
    [10] => more
)
```

In fact, I want to merge the array elements when two delimiters are neighbors. In other words, ignoring the first delimiter if the next part is the second delimiter.

Comment: Your last paragraph is something that can not be done with regex. You need custom code for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a character class: `/[ ,]+/`

The `+` is a quantifier meaning "1 or more"

Comment: The `CAPTURE` feature of `preg_split` only works for delimiters within parenthesis. With `[ ]`, we cannot capture the delimiters.

Comment: Could you put parens around the brackets?

Comment: my bad! yes, it can be simply placed within the parenthesis, I just saw the brackets as replacements.

Comment: Is it possible to use this structure for delimiters longer than 1 character?

Answer (score 2):

What about making sure that the situation doesn't happen in the first place :

```
<?php
    $str = "this is a test , and more";
    $str=preg_replace('/ *, */',',',$str);
    $array = preg_split('/( |,)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    print_r($array);
?>

Array
(
    [0] => this
    [1] =>  
    [2] => is
    [3] =>  
    [4] => a
    [5] =>  
    [6] => test
    [7] => ,
    [8] => and
    [9] =>  
    [10] => more
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `/([, ]+)/` it works. See **[codepad](http://codepad.org/awjlapHN)**